# How do restart a batch file every 15 minutes using Powershell

Tags: powershell, cron, scheduler

How do restart a batch file every 15 minutes using Powershell? or start a batch file every 15 minutes will do, I will put kill process line on top of the file so it kills before the actual application runs. Windows Task Schedule only runs the task in the background. I need to have the application runs on foreground
Or maybe equivalent of crontab for Windows?
Thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

Task Scheduler can run an application on foreground.
See [`-LogonType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtaskprincipal?view=windowsserver2019-ps)
`-LogonType Interactive` or `-LogonType InteractiveOrPassword`
A user must be logged on. I'm not sure if the process is interactive when the currently logged on user is different than the credentials stored for the task.